# Proof using Gronwall inequality

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

Using the Gronwall inequality, how do I show that if:

$$\partial_t \log (1 + u(t) ^2) <1$$

Such that $u(t)$ is a solution of the differential equation :

$$\dot x(t) = - ax(t)+ \log (1+x(t)^2)\quad(a>1) $$

Then any $u(t)$ tends to $0$ when $t\to+\infty $.

Remark: I already proved any $u(t)$ is defined for all real $t$.

I tried to show that when  $t\to+ \infty $ ,  $\log (1 + u(t) ^2) \leq 0$ and therefore $u(t)$ must tend to zero.

Comment: Sorry but this makes little sense. What is $x$? What is $\partial_t$? Why is the condition relevant to study the ODE? Why is $\log(1+u^2)\leqslant0$ (which is impossible since $1+u^2\gt1$ unless $u=0$...)? And Gronwall??

Comment: Still absurd. $ $

Comment: The Gronwall inequality can be helpful http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gronwall%27s_inequality. I'm trying to find an appropriate \beta (t)

Comment: ??? Of course it can--but not here.

Comment: "I'm trying to find an appropriate $\beta(t)$" First comment relevant...